# quicksort with linked lists

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list, quicksort

I have written down the following program that uses the quicksort algorithm to sort how ever many ints are put into the command line using linked lists. Not only am I getting an ISO C90 error about mixed declarations but there is a memory leak somewhere in my code and I am not sure how to fix it. Any help would be appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "linked_list.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "memcheck.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

node *quicksort(node *list);
int ListLength (node *list);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1) {
    fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [-q] number1 number2 ... \
    (must enter at least one argument)\n", argv[0]);
    exit(1);
    }
    node *list;
    node *sorted_list;
    int i;
    int intArg = 0; /* number of integer arguments */
    int print = 1;
    /* if -q is found anywhere then we are going 
     * to change the behavior of the program so that
     * it still sorts but does not print the result */
    for ( i = 1 ; i < argc; i++) {
        if (strcmp(argv[i], "-q") == 0) {
            print = 0;
        }
        else {
            list = create_node(atoi(argv[i]), list); /* memory allocation in the           create_node function */
            intArg++; }
    }

    if (intArg == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: %s [-q] number1 number2 ...\
       (at least one of the input arguments must be an integer)\n", argv[0]); 
        exit(1); }
    sorted_list = quicksort(list);
    free_list(list);
    list = sorted_list;
    if (print == 1) {
        print_list(list); }
    print_memory_leaks();
    return 0; } 

/* This function sorts a linked list using the quicksort
 * algorithm */
node *quicksort(node *list) {
node *less=NULL, *more=NULL, *next, *temp=NULL, *end;
node *pivot = list;
if (ListLength(list) <= 1) {
    node *listCopy;
    listCopy = copy_list(list);
    return listCopy; }
else {
    next = list->next;
    list = next;
    /* split into two */
    temp = list;
    while(temp != NULL) {
        next = temp->next;
        if (temp->data < pivot->data) {
            temp->next = less;
            less = temp;
   }
        else {
            temp->next = more;
            more = temp;
  }
        temp = next;
  }
    less = quicksort(less);
    more = quicksort(more); }
   /* appending the results */
if (less != NULL) {
    end = less;
    while (end->next != NULL) {
        end = end->next;
  } 
pivot->next = more;
end->next = pivot;
return less; }
else {
    pivot->next = more;
return pivot; } } 
int ListLength (node *list) {
    node *temp = list;
    int i=0;
    while(temp!=NULL) {
        i++; 
        temp=temp->next; }
return i; }
```

Comment: What is the compiler error message?  How do you know there is a memory leak?

Comment: it starts out by allocating memory then it prints a couple of the numbers i entered in the correct order but stop and prints memory leak   line:78 and later on line 20 a bunch of times.

Comment: The mixed declaration error is probably down to checking argc before declaring your variables. I get this if I compile with -pedantic flag in gcc.

Comment: that fixes that problem thanks! However, the code is still not functional.

Comment: Where is the code for create_node?

Comment: node *
copy_list(node *list)
{
    if (list == NULL)
    {
        return list;
    }
    else
    {
        node *new_list;

        new_list = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

        if (new_list == NULL)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: out of memory. "
                    "Terminating program.\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        new_list->data = list->data;
        new_list->next = copy_list(list->next);
        return new_list;
    }
}

Comment: You should add the code to your question, since its hard to read the comment.  Also add the create_node function and other node functions that you have, like free_list.  So we can see the memory allocations and cleanup.

Comment: Please don't tag your question *c++* if it's actually *c*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `main`, you free one node, the original head of the list:

```
sorted_list = quicksort(list);
free_list(list);
```

But you never free any other node, although you copy the nodes. So all the original list nodes save from the first are floating in unreachable memory. Either `free` on copy, but then don't `free` in `main`, or don't copy at all (and free all nodes in `main`, but only after you no longer need them).

Comment: you are not correct. The only other node in main is sorted_list which does not solve the problem when freed.

Comment: I would expect `list = create_node(atoi(argv[i]), list);` to allocate nodes, especially given the comment on that line. You never have a direct reference to any but one (possibly two after sorting) of them in main. Then in `quicksort` you `copy_list` the nodes when you reach length 1, forgetting about the original node. Thus you assemble the sorted list from copied nodes whose original isn't freed (and usually becomes unreachable soon). Also, `list` points to the original head, which is the first pivot. Pivots aren't copied, so it is part of the sorted list. ...

Comment: When you `free` it, you tear the sorted list, its predecessor now has a dangling pointer and the nodes after it are no longer reachable (but you may not notice, if its never overwritten).

Answer (score 1):

Well, you haven't posted the code for `free_list()` or `create_node()` which are prime candidates for potential memory leaks, but I believe your `quicksort()` code has a memory leak here:

```
    less = quicksort(less);
    more = quicksort(more); }
```

if either list has only one element, then this code:

```
if (ListLength(list) <= 1) {
    node *listCopy;
    listCopy = copy_list(list);
    return listCopy; }
```

returns a copy of the one element. By setting the `less` and `more` pointers here, you potentially lose a single node.

Consider the list: `2 1 3`

The code would add `1` to the `less` list, and `3` to the `more` list. Then it would perform `quicksort()` on these two one-element lists, return a copy of the list, and lose the pointers to the original `less` and `more` lists, resulting in a memory leak of two nodes.

Coincidentally, it would be better to replace the check of the `if` statement above with:

```
if (list == NULL || list->next == NULL) {
```

This avoids having to traverse a potentially long list just to check if it only contains 0 or 1 elements.