# QUICKSORT on single linked list

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a simply C code for QUICKSORT on single linked list. Program will get a txt file with password and frequency of usage this password. Program should sort the passwords in order. Can someone guess what is wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>


typedef struct list_element{
    char passwort[100];
    int haufigkeit;
    struct list_element *next;
} list_element;

typedef struct list{
    list_element *first;
    list_element *last;
} list;


void init_list(list* mylist)
{
    mylist->first=NULL;
    mylist->last=NULL;
}


// Diese Funktion fügt Listenelemente am Anfang der Liste an
void insert_front(list_element* le, list* mylist)
{
    if(mylist->first == NULL){
        le->next = mylist-> first;
        mylist->first=le;
        mylist->last=le;
    }
    else {
        le->next = mylist-> first;
        mylist->first= le;
    }
}

// Speicher für Listenelemente wieder freigeben
void free_list(list* mylist)
{
    free((mylist)->first);
    free(mylist);
    mylist=NULL;
}


// Namen, Zahlen Paare in Liste einlesen
void read_data(char* filename, list* mylist)
{
    assert(mylist != NULL);
    FILE* f=fopen(filename,"r");
    assert(f != NULL);
    while (1)
    {
        list_element* temp = malloc(sizeof(list_element));// * Speicher allozieren
        fscanf(f,"%s %d",temp->passwort, &temp-> haufigkeit);// * Daten in list_element einlesen
        insert_front(temp, mylist); // * insert_front benutzen um list_element in Liste einzufügen
    }
    fclose(f);
}

// Pivot finden, das die Liste aufteilt
list_element* partition( list* input, list* left, list* right ){
list_element* pivot= input->first;

    while(input->first != input->last){
        list_element *i;
        for(i=input->first; i != NULL; i=i->next){
            if ((i -> haufigkeit) < (pivot -> haufigkeit)){
                insert_front( i, left);
            }
            else{
                insert_front( i, right);
            }
        }
    }
    return pivot;
}

void print_list(list* mylist){

    list_element* current =mylist-> first;
    while(current != NULL){
        printf("%d %c \n",current->passwort,current->haufigkeit);
        current=current->next;
    }
}
// Hauptfunktion des quicksort Algorithmus
void qsort_list(list* mylist){
    // HIER Code einfügen
    // list liste= mylist;
    list *right;
    list *left;
    list_element* pivot;
    while(mylist->first != mylist->last){
        partition(mylist, left, right );
    qsort_list(left);
    qsort_list(right);
    }
}

// Liste ausgeben

// Argumente einlesen, Liste kreieren, verarbeiten und ausgeben
int main(int argc, char** args)
{
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Nutzung: %s <Dateiname>\n",args[0]);
        return 1;
    }
    list mylist;
    init_list(&mylist);
    read_data(args[1],&mylist);
    qsort_list(&mylist);
    printf("Sortierte Liste:\n");
    print_list(&mylist);
    free_list(&mylist);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "_Can someone guess what is wrong here?"_, since when do people use SO to let people guess what's wrong with their code?

Comment: Look on the right for similar questions. In this case the same question was asked before [quicksort of linked list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423885/quicksort-with-linked-lists?rq=1).

Comment: Agh! Indent your code!

Comment: I'm guessing that you didn't do any debugging and just dumped your non-working code here to get someone else to do the hard work for free.  Of course, I could be wrong...

Comment: Don't comment your code in German, Spanish, Swahili or anything else: do it in English. Even for your small private stuff. You can never be sure where you're gonna post those snippets...

Answer (score 1):

When do you intent to `break` from this code snippet?

```
while (1)
{
  list_element* temp = malloc(sizeof(list_element));// * Speicher allozieren
  fscanf(f,"%s %d",temp->passwort, &temp-> haufigkeit);// * Daten in list_element einlesen
  insert_front(temp, mylist); // * insert_front benutzen um list_element in Liste einzufügen
}
```

PS: and there is no sense in posting german comments. Please indent the code and remove/translate the comments

Comment: Thank you! that was a problem :)